# Get only largestChangeId in smart way

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

I am new to this Google Drive SDK. Using Drive as cloud storage for my app. App needs to sync the data in largestChangeId appdata folder. For the first time App needs to get the largestChangeId using changeList API.I believe that the result of changelist API include all details.Which are not interest to me. I am just interested in largestChangeId to store locally to subscribe for changes feed in future.

1. How can I tune [changeList API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list#examples) to just get only largestChangeId?
2. Are there any other alternative way or API to do this in smart way?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get largestChangeId only by using About.get() with fields parameter specified.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about?fields=largestChangeId
```

This will simply return

```
{
   "largestChangeId": "{{WHAT_YOU_WANTED}}";
}
```

And you're already doing it in a smart way :)

Comment: Link to documentation [About get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get)